# python google trans module

Tags: python, module

Is there a way in the google trans module instead of it showing `Translated(src=en, dest=es, text=Hola, pronunciation=None, extra_data="{'translat...")` it will only show `text=Hola`?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the value returned is a `Translated` object.
You can *extract* the text from it by doing `TranslatedObjVar.text`, where `TranslatedObjVar` is the variable where you store this `Translated` object.

For more details, check out https://stackabuse.com/text-translation-with-google-translate-api-in-python/

Comment: pigeon it says    out = traslator.translate(TranslatedObjVar.text,my_entry_trans.get(), dest='es')
NameError: name 'TranslatedObjVar' is not defined, |||| I dont really understand where i should put it

Comment: @evan_tech1234 In my example, what I considered as TranslatedObjVar is what you considered as out

Comment: If you haven't defined a variable before, you will get a ```NameError```. What I meant was, save the output of the ```translator.translate()``` output to (say) ```var``` and then you can access the text through ```var.text```. 

You may check out the link provided in the answer for more clarity and for an example of this too :)